# How to force MarkupExtension to bind again

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, binding

I want to force my custom extension to bind again when my language change:

```
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(string))]
public class TranalstionExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return Translator.Translate(this.Translate);
    }

    public string Translate { get; set; }
}
```

in usage:

```
<Button Content="{t:Tranalstion Translate=plus}"/>
```

I'm changing the language on the same Window so now it should return into property different translation, how to force `MarkupExtension` to do this but not only for `Content` property but for all occurrence of my extension mechanism on window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data source has to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged event.

```
public override object ProvideValue( IServiceProvider serviceProvider )
{
    var binding = new Binding( "Value" )
    {
        Source = new TranslationData( this.Translate )
    };
    return binding.ProvideValue( serviceProvider );
}
```

TranslationData then has to take care of getting informed about a langauge change and fire the PropertyChanged event.